# Handling numeric variables with special (non-physical) value in GAM model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, gam

I'm building a GAM model using mgcv and I have a feature like the following:

```
value:  -1000     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8 
count:  42943   978  1069   402   145    43     7     1     1     1
```

This feature has a special value -1000 which means no record. Only the >0 values have physical meanings.

Using a smoothing spline for the whole range doesn't make sense as the distance between -1000 to >0 is not meaningful.

Converting this variable into a categorical factor variable and using a piecewise constant function is also not very convenient sometimes, as the training (testing) set could easily miss a factor level if there are so many discrete values.

Is there any good way to handle this type of features? I don't want to simply drop them as the >0 part still provides some discriminating power.

Comment: What happens if you replace them with NA?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the fact that, as you said, "-1000 which means no record", so you can't treat this variable as a scale variable as it is, because -1000 is more like a symbol rather than a number (even if you had negative values).

So, the change/transformation you will do has to have an objective, as you can try various things.
I guess the objective here is to increase the predictive power of your model.
This means trying various transformations and see what happens.
You can try :

a) Replace -1000 with NAs

b) Create a categorical variable by grouping this variable as ranges (maybe based on quantiles), but get a reasonable number of ranges. Something like "no record", "0","1","2+". Maybe create a decision or regression tree (depending on your outcome variable) and let it split your variable into groups.

c) If "no record" means "missing record" and not "there's no record", then you might consider getting that record somehow, as the "no record" cases are the 94% of the cases of that column. This might mean a simple split of that variable to "no record" and "record exists".

Comment: Thanks! I think your suggestions make sense to me.